# HTML details / summary background color when the details opens

Tags: html, css

On mobile (tested on `iOS`) when you touch (click) the `<details>` to open it, its background (whatever it is) color changes for a few **milliseconds**. I have tried to use the same background color when it gets the focus, but it does not work.

```css
details {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FDF4E3;;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
}

summary {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 2.2rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

details[open] summary {
   background: #F9D478;
}

details:focus,
details:hover,
details:active {
  background: #FDF4E3;
}

summary:focus,
summary:hover,
summary:active {
  background: none;
}


details p {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Summary</summary>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque porro odit nulla quis voluptas quod similique sunt, nostrum, ea maxime repellendus quisquam harum tempore illum sed, dolore qui aperiam impedit!
  </p>
</details>
```

Github Coplilot has used  details, it has the same issue.

[Frequently asked questions](https://github.com/features/copilot/) - https://github.com/features/copilot/

Spotify has used also details that has the same issue.

https://www.spotify.com/uk/duo/

Does anyone know how to prevent  background color (whatever it is) of details / summary from being changed?

Comment: Did you try to style `:focus`, `:hover` and `:active`?

Comment: @Jax-p yes. updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar behaviour with Chrome on an Android mobile.
Each time I touched the `<summary>` to open the `<details>`, the `<summary>` background changed for about half a second.
Playing with all **pseudo css** classes to manipulate the `background` didn't help.

Finally (and surprisingly), I found that resetting the `cursor` solved the problem.
By using a media query, I set `cursor` for mobile (to solve the problem) and non-mobiles (to show the 'hand' mouse pointer on e.g. Windows):

```
/* for mobiles */
summary {cursor: unset;} 

/* for non-mobiles */
@media screen and (min-width: 817px)  {
    {cursor: pointer;}
}
```

Note: My 'non-mobile' criteria (817px) is only used in my private environment (app for a heating control). Probably, you should use a different one.